# Is there a way to compare times in an xpath expression?

Tags: xml, xpath

So, for my XML I have this:

```
<venues>
<venue venueID="1">
  <name>Nillington Center</name>
  <location>Nullville</location>
  <capacity>10000</capacity>
  <openingTime>07:00:00</openingTime>
  <closingTime>22:00:00</closingTime>
  <Manager>DJ8S1L0</Manager>
  <telephone>01101 111011</telephone>
</venue>
```

Is it possible to construct an Xpath expression that could calculate, assuming there are multiple venues, openingTime > '18:00:00' and if so, how?

comparison works fine for integers, for example I have no problem in getting something like 
    `/venues/venue[capacity > 8000]` to work but not for time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
venues/venue[number(translate(substring(openingTime, 1, 5), ":", ".")) &gt; 18]
```

Steps:

- get rid of the seconds part (I assume this is unimportant)
- swap out the ":" for a decimal so the string is primed for numeric conversion (in other words, 18:00 becomes 18.00)
- convert the hours and minutes part to a number (this renders the comparison valid)

Comment: hmm, when I try that in a validator it says that its not a valid xpath expression, however `venues/venue[number(closingTime) > 18] `
works with the time format in the XML changed to "23.00"